# Dimmer switch with ceiling fan instead of remote

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

Is there any reason to use a remote control with a ceiling fan (that most come with), which requires a battery and can get lost, when a simple dimmer switch can be installed to regulate the speed? Is it, for some reason, bad to use a dimmer switch with a ceiling fan? This assumes the fan does have a separate wall switch and is not directly wired with a chain switch, like some old ones used to.

Comment: Is this a fan-only situation or a fan with a light kit?

Comment: Fan only situation

Answer (score 1):

## A brief taxonomy of fan controllers

Ceiling fan speed controllers come in a variety of flavors, but there are only a few general types in the market that provide more than On/Off control:

- Receiverless wallbox -- your garden variety "Fan speed controller" that only controls fan speed.  All the control logic is found in the controller in the wallbox, and it expects to be wired to a fan only.  Controlling a light kit is done using a separate wire from the wallbox to the fan.
- Receiver Wallbox -- high-end fan or fan/light controllers such as the Lutron Maestro.  These use a wallbox controller that communicates with a canopy-mounted receiver via the powerline between the wallbox and the fan.  They are in some ways the most flexible as they support multi-way control of both the fan and the light and also may support home automation, but handheld remotes are rare here.
- Receiver Wireless -- your cheap "fan remote" that comes with a fan.  These also use a canopy-mounted receiver module, but it is purely RF-based using a proprietary RF protocol to communicate with the battery powered transmitter-remote.  Their cheapness means they don't support any fancy home automation functions or multi-way controls, and some only provide limited fan speed or light control compared to wallbox controllers.

## ...and why you shouldn't use a light dimmer to control a fan

Light dimmers are built to switch *lights* -- a lightbulb is a relatively benign load compared to a fan, at least as far as a dimmer's switching element (triac) is concerned.  This means that cheap dimmers are built using cheap triacs and minimal external snubbing, leaving them unprotected against accidental (premature) turn-on or worse due to what are called dI/dt and dV/dt effects.

Furthermore, a dimmer starts the lights at *low* coming from the off state.  This is fine for incandescent (or even CFL/LED) lightbulbs, as they don't care.  But, a motor that's managed through variable voltage needs to be brought up to speed after starting *then* slowed.

Fan speed controllers use more rugged triacs and extra snubber circuits to survive the dI/dt and dV/dt abuses imposed by driving a fan, and they also start the fan motor at maximum speed, then let you turn it down.